# Single liner for converting dictionary values into a separate dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary dict1 whose values are also dictionaries

```
dict1 = 
  {
   0: {'test1': ['pass', 'pass']},
   1: {'test2': ['fail', 'pass']},
   2: {'test3': ['fail', 'fail']},
   3: {'test4': []},
   4: {'test5': ['pass']},
   5: {'test6': ['pass', 'pass']}
  }
```

I want to get its values as a separate dictionary dict2, I have tried like this

```
dict2 = {k:v for k,v in dict(dict1.values()).items()}
```

I am getting an error below

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Expected Output

```
dict2 =
      {
      'test1': ['pass', 'pass'],
      'test2': ['fail', 'pass'],
      'test3': ['fail', 'fail'],
      'test4': [],
      'test5': ['pass'],
      'test6': ['pass', 'pass']
      }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict`:

```
dict2 = dict(b for i in dict1.values() for b in i.items())
```

Output:

```
{'test1': ['pass', 'pass'], 
 'test2': ['fail', 'pass'], 
 'test3': ['fail', 'fail'], 
 'test4': [], 
 'test5': ['pass'], 
 'test6': ['pass', 'pass']
}
```

Comment: I just got one too    This code seems fine to me, although a dictionary comprehension is probably considered more Pythonic than sending a generator expression into `dict`.

Comment: @wim It probably is, although RoadRunner has already provided a solution with a dict comprehension :)

Answer (score 3):

You can *splat the dict values into a [chain map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
>>> from collections import ChainMap
>>> dict(ChainMap(*dict1.values()))
{'test6': ['pass', 'pass'],
 'test5': ['pass'],
 'test4': [],
 'test3': ['fail', 'fail'],
 'test2': ['fail', 'pass'],
 'test1': ['pass', 'pass']}
```

Actually a chain map is also a type of mapping (similar API to a dict) so you may not need the outer dict call at all. If you care to preserve ordering, then splat the values in with [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because of `dict(dict1.values())`. You are casting `dict()` to `dict_values([{'test1': ['pass', 'pass']}, {'test2': ['fail', 'pass']},...])`, which is not a valid type to convert to a dictionary, since the inner dictionaries are of length 1 instead of 2, as the error suggests. You can verify this with `[len(x) for x in dict1.values()]`, which will return `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

To get the result you desire, you can use this [dictionary comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html#dictionary-comprehension):

```
>>> {key: value for inner_dict in dict1.values() for key, value in inner_dict.items()}
{'test1': ['pass', 'pass'], 'test2': ['fail', 'pass'], 'test3': ['fail', 'fail'], 'test4': [], 'test5': ['pass'], 'test6': ['pass', 'pass']}
```

Which will first iterate over the `values()` of `dict1`(since we don't need the outermost key). Then it will iterate the `items()` of the inner dict `inner_dict` and assign the key value pairs `key: value`.

The above is the same as the following *nested loop* approach:

```
result = {}
for inner_dict in dict1.values():
    for key, value in inner_dict.items():
        result[key] = value

print(result)
# {'test1': ['pass', 'pass'], 'test2': ['fail', 'pass'], 'test3': ['fail', 'fail'], 'test4': [], 'test5': ['pass'], 'test6': ['pass', 'pass']}
```

Which might be easier to read if you are not familiar with dict comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest loops in dict comprehensions.

```
dict2 = {k: v for d in dict1.values() for k, v in d.items()}
```

The above one-liner roughly is equivalent to

```
dict2 = {}
for d in dict1.values():
    for k, v in d.items():
        dict2[k] = v
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I posted?